# Are spiritual interpretation of Mythological events on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As my question above states, are spiritual interpretation of Mythological events on-topic?

Just for example, if you look at this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2775/93), which explains that Amrit (*nectar*) is actually knowledge but not any liquid. This answer was nicely explained and as we can see most of the users agree with the explanation. But In my opinion, this answer sounds as one's perspective understanding of Mythological events which could raise opinion based answers (*which is off-topic*).

According to me, if my assumption is correct then I think these type of interpretations should be included as sub-section in their post.

Comment: You're right, it does invite too much opinion and speculation, so I think it should just be off-topic, not even included in a sub-section.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think they should atleast include as sub-section. because it is really helpful to look in that perspective. (_atleast to me_). The link which I posted in my question explains the situation beautifully.

Comment: But the answer you linked to is just pure speculation.  It's not grounded in source or references, it's just an arbitrary personal theory.  That's exactly what we should avoid in the site.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I agree, but what I was thinking is that if a user is capable of seeing the things in different speculation and wanted to share his thoughts then he should be encouraged but to a extent or restriction that it should be sub-topic in his answer. Though they are opinion based having them as sub-topic will let users to think before posting the answer. I know this will be tough but it is just a thought of mine. I would be happy even if somehow they are included in different way, which I couldn't think of.

Comment: Adding spiritual interpretations would enable different people to post different interpretations, which is simply confusion for the OP and also not conclusive. Posting references help in some way.

Comment: BUT I also believe the question also has to be taken into account. For a question such as the one posted by the OP, the question deals with "Is there an actual existence of nectar?", for which a spiritual interpretation would also be an answer. Because the OP begins by saying that he/she has heard of a story in Hinduism and would like to know if this 'nectar' is actually existent. Please feel free to share your thoughts.

Comment: @Sai even if it is with reference, the other user might have answer in different perspective taken from another reference. Because spiritual interpretation is not present in scriptures. Am I right?

Comment: If I am right, what I propose is that users should share this kind of thoughts as sub-section in answer.

Comment: @Mr_Green yes you are right in one way, but the question is is this forum only dealing with quoting from scriptures? or is there room for people to elucidate on their understanding of the same, given some references? My view is this, look at the question and then decide if it is appropriate or not. For some questions it might be okay, for some questions it might be unnecessary.

Comment: @Sai not only scriptures but also valid sources are ok but in this case even if we have valid sources, the answers could varies because spiritual interpretation is one's way of understanding the events. So, it will lead to opinion based answers. In short, there could be possibility that a event could be explained differently in different sources. Coming to your answer, IMO, it should be kept open on a one condition that the spiritual interpretation is taken in to account as sub-section. If we make spiritual interpretation as completely off-topic then no one will find spirituality in this site.

Comment: Are you talking about questions or answers? as question can be on-topic or off-topic not answers. Yes, such type of answers can be considered as opinions if not cited with scriptural references.